# is it possible to lock windows phone 7 device programmatically

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to lock the windows phone 7 programmatically. I checked this forum I found out that till feb 2011 there was no API provided for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There still isn't. There is no good reason to frustrate a user with locking the Phone.

Let the user decide!

Comment: There are some good scenarios where this would be helpful... For example, having a clock app that upon user tap locks the screen.

Comment: @swinefeaster - I would never expect a phone to lock after tapping a clock. A lock is not a clock.

Comment: What about this scenario: 
- user launches clock in evening and goes to bed
- when someone taps the clock, it should ask for pin to unlock the phone for security reasons

This is what Android does and it is very useful and not unexpected at all.... especially if the clock has been running for > 5 min

Comment: @swinefeaster - That might be a situation that would need this feature. An alternative would be to allow the creation of lock screen apps (screensaver apps)